# Android app can use bluetooth without ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to operate a bluetooth printer through my android app. I came across following documentation page which describes how to use bluetooth from an android app.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

In this documentation, it says that the app should declare it needs `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission.

Then I came across following github project of an android app which can operate a bluetooth printer.

https://github.com/deysuman/Android-Bluetooth-printer

But in this github project, it can be seen that `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` is not declared in its manifest. But this app works fine without a problem.

So, How does this app work without declaring `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`?

Comment: Note that its targetSDKVersion is 24.  Which means it gets to play by an old set of rules.  Of course, this type of app wouldn't be allowed on the Play Store anymore (minimum is 26 or 27 IIRC).  If you bump the targetSDKVersion it may no longer work.

Comment: @GabeSechan good observation, but actually I had to bump the targetSdkVersion to 28 to get it compiled, but it still works. I am testing the app on android 6.0. Can this be the case?

Comment: That could definitely be why.  I don't think that privacy push came until later.  Google's docs tend to only be accurate for the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

The build.gradle file of that project targets an older Android API (24) which did not have that requirement.